# Vim paste before cursor

Tags: vim

I have a selection in a register that includes no new lines. For example:

`Happy-`

I would like to paste this selection at the start of a line. Say for example:

`New-Year`

To result in:

`Happy-New-Year`

Since `New-Year` is at the start of a line, the leftmost I can place my cursor is over the `N`:

`[N]ew-Year`

If I press `p` in normal mode, I get the following:

`NHappy-ew-Year`

Is there a variation to `p` that I can use to paste before my cursor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As often, capitalization makes the difference: `p` pastes after, `P` pastes before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can paste a selection before your cursor by using `[p` in normal mode. If your cursor is on `N`:

`[N]ew-Year`

And you have `Happy-` in your default register, `[p` will result in:

`Happy-New-Year`

This can also be applied to non-default registers. For example, if `Happy-` is in register `a` you can paste before the cursor by executing: `"a[p`

Comment: Vim's help for `[p` says: `like "P", but adjust indent to current line`. There's a simpler answer: Just use `P`. Not to mention that if you have a linewise yank (from `Y`) then using `[p` will change the leading spaces/tabs